# maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison with circular references

Tags: python, recursion, comparison

I was working with students creating a simple demo of a finite state machine:

```
s2 = {}
s1 = {}
s1["0"] = s2
s1["1"] = s1
s2["0"] = s1
s2["1"] = s2
machine = {"start": s1, "accepting": [s1]}

def recognize(fsm, in_string):
    return do_recognize(fsm, fsm["start"], in_string)

def do_recognize(fsm, current, in_string):
    if len(in_string) == 0:
        return current in fsm["accepting"]

   return do_recognize(fsm, current[in_string[0]] ,
                 in_string[1:])

print (recognize(machine, "0"))
```

This machine recognizes strings with an even number of 0s, and it works fine on "good" strings (such as "1" or "010").  But on a "bad" string such as the one above, it gets
into an infinite loop and then stack overflow at return current in fsm["accepting"].

I was able to determine that the problem is the comparison of the two states.  In fact I can generate the exact same bug by just writing s1 == s2.  But s1 == s1 (a good state) works fine.

My best guess of what's happening is that it's doing a deep compare and trying to follow all of the references in s2, which are circular.  But why is it asymmetrical (i.e. why doesn't s1 == s1 have the same problem)?  And how can I avoid it?

Comment: Are you the instructor on this course?

Comment: You can avoid this by adhering to the "flat is better than nested" idiom; represent states by strings (or ints) and the transition table as a single `dict`.

Comment: I would guess that `s1 == s1` first checks to see if the dictionaries have the same `id` and return `True` if they do.  `s1 == s2` would have to compare the dictoraries' contents.

Comment: Jon: Yes, I am.  Thanks for the suggestion, larsmans, that's probably the right way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compare dictionaries, each item (key/value pair) in the dictionary is compared as well, so if you have circular references between dictionaries **where the circular references involve the same keys**, you will get this maximum recursion depth exceeded error when comparing them:

For example, if you have `s1 == {'0': s2}` and `s2 == {'0': s1}`, then attempting `s1 == s2` will result in the following comparisons, which illustrates how the recursion occurs:

```
s1 == s2 --> s1['0'] == s2['0'] --> s2 == s1 --> s2['0'] == s1['0'] --> s1 == s2 --> ...
```

A containment test like `s1 in [s2]` or `s2 in [s1]` will result in this equality comparison as well, which is why it happens in your code at `current in fsm["accepting"]`.

You can work around this recursion issue by using an identity comparison instead of an equality comparison, just replace `current in fsm["accepting"]` with the following:

```
any(s is current for s in fsm["accepting"])
```

A better solution might be to not use circular references by having the states refer to an identifier instead of the object itself, for example you could have a structure like the following:

```
states = {"s1": {"0": "s2", "1": "s1"},
          "s2": {"0": "s1", "1": "s2"}}
machine = {"start": "s1", "accepting": ["s1"]}

def recognize(fsm, in_string):
    return do_recognize(fsm, fsm["start"], in_string)

def do_recognize(fsm, current, in_string):
    if len(in_string) == 0:
        return current in fsm["accepting"]
    return do_recognize(fsm, states[current][in_string[0]], in_string[1:])
```

Comment: Thanks F.J., great answer.  The second solution is clearly the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

The problem has to do with circular references between `s1` and `s2`.

This makes it impossible to compare `s1` to `s2` (as far as `cmp()` is concerned, the two dictionaries have infinite depth). Consider the following:

```
print s1 == s1 # immediately returns True, probably due to equal object ids
print s1 == s2 # RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

This explains why `s1 in fsm["accepting"]` works, and `s2 in fsm["accepting"]` breaks.

An easy way to fix this is to replace

```
return current in fsm["accepting"]
```

with

```
return id(current) in map(id, fsm["accepting"])
```

This compares states by identity instead of trying to compare two infinitely-deep dictionaries by value.

Comment: Thanks NPE, I did not know about id